# Shortening Path variable

Tags: windows, environment-variables, path

Currently, my `PATH` variable is way too long. It seems to have been populated by different programs upon installation. I have pasted my `PATH` variable below. Could you please tell me if it is safe to remove any of the file paths?

Here's the list using separate lines for readability:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter\Driver;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;
C:\MinGW64\mingw32\bin
```

Comment: what sort of problems you face due to length of your PATH variable?

Comment: Why do you have  spaces after the the `;` in your `PATH`?  That causes broken behaviour. Remove those spaces and try again.

Comment: It would be up to you to check what paths physically exist and decide if you actually use parts of stuff that is stored in those locations.